# SQL query to extract characters between the strings and making new rows and columns

Tags: sql, regex, string, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

So I have a table that contains long text which is basically the recorded changes if I change some items in my profile settings. I need to extract what items that I changed, and also the before and after of the text in the items.

The table is as follows:

**main_table**

| id | date | string |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | company_id:;- ;- 1;name:;- ABC;- ABC(new) ;address:;- tokyo tower;- kyoto tower; |

So from the main_table above, I can see that I change 3 items in my profile setting, my company id from **null to 1**, my name from **ABC to ABC(new)**, and my address from **tokyo tower to kyoto tower**.

The patter than I can confirm is that the item name always ends with **a colon (:)**, example from above is **company_id:**,  **name:** and **address:**. While the text  changes is always between **two semicolon (;string;)**

My expected result would be like this:

| id | date | changed_items | before | after |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | company_id | null | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | name | ABC | ABC(new) |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | address | tokyo tower | kyoto tower |

I've tried using regex and cross join

```
select *
from main_table 
cross join unnest(regexp_extract_all(string,'(?<=\;)(.*?)(?=\;)')) as u(str_modified)
```

And ended up with this result

| id | date | string | str_modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | company_id:;- ;- 1;name:;- ABC;- ABC(new) ;address:;- tokyo tower;- kyoto tower; | - |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | company_id:;- ;- 1;name:;- ABC;- ABC(new) ;address:;- tokyo tower;- kyoto tower; | - 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | company_id:;- ;- 1;name:;- ABC;- ABC(new) ;address:;- tokyo tower;- kyoto tower; | name: |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | company_id:;- ;- 1;name:;- ABC;- ABC(new) ;address:;- tokyo tower;- kyoto tower; | - ABC |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | company_id:;- ;- 1;name:;- ABC;- ABC(new) ;address:;- tokyo tower;- kyoto tower; | - ABC(new) |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | company_id:;- ;- 1;name:;- ABC;- ABC(new) ;address:;- tokyo tower;- kyoto tower; | address: |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | company_id:;- ;- 1;name:;- ABC;- ABC(new) ;address:;- tokyo tower;- kyoto tower; | - tokyo tower |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 | company_id:;- ;- 1;name:;- ABC;- ABC(new) ;address:;- tokyo tower;- kyoto tower; | - kyoto tower |

Which is not quite what I need, is there any way to do this in sql? I'm using athena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```sql
with data as (
  select 'company_id:;- ;- 1;name:;- ABC;- ABC(new) ;address:;- tokyo tower;- kyoto tower;' as col
),
numbers as (select 1 as num union select 4 union select 7)

select
  REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(col, ';', num), ':', '') as changed_items,
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(col, ';- ', ';'), ';', num+1) as before,
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(col, ';- ', ';'), ';', num+2) as after
  
from data
cross join numbers
order by num
```

produces:

| changed_items | before | after |
| --- | --- | --- |
| company_id |  | 1 |
| name | ABC | ABC(new) |
| address | tokyo tower | kyoto tower |

The first thing to realise is that one input row is producing **multiple output rows**. Therefore, it needs some way of generating additional rows. Using `UNNEST` can do this, but it cannot work on triplets (item, before, after). To address this, the query joins with another table that contains `1, 4, 7` to process the triplets on separate output lines.

These numbers are then used to extract specific elements (`1, 2, 3` and `4, 5, 6` and `7, 8, 9`) to display on each row. There is also a bit of cleanup for the hyphens and colons.

To use the query, you can remove the `data` CTE and join to your actual table.